# Is there a collaborative text editor like gobby, but that doesn't crash easily?

Tags: windows, text-editor

Is there a collaborative text editor like gobby (live; not a web-app), but that doesn't crash easily?

Let's say a file is stored on one computer, then you open it in the text editor on that computer.  Then through file sharing, you open it from another computer, and each one updates the other (a bit like Google Docs).

Gobby does that, but can crash easily.

Further info:

> What features (like formatting, integrating images etc) do you need?

I don't want those features.  Just a text editor please.

> What OS(es) must be supported?

Windows and preferably OS X too.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Could you please **[edit]** your question accordingly? E.g. what features (like formatting, integrating images etc) do you need? How much you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid solutions? What OS(es) must be supported?

Comment: @Izzy gobby does not include any formatting or integrating images, so no I don't want those features. I said text editor that means text editor

Comment: Well, I never heard of Gobby. And you also mentioned Google Docs. If there is a product that meets your needs, and someone is using it but hasn't heard of Gobby either – how would that someone know it would answer your question? That's why we insist a question must be complete and self-contained.

Comment: @Izzy I said " each one updates the other a bit like google docs."   So it is clear from context what aspect of google docs I am referring to. Most of my question says like gobby but without mentined problem with gobby. And I said text editor.  somebody that doesn't know what gobby is probably won't know of such software.

Comment: will check out office 2019 and office 365

Comment: Uh? You've asked for (plain) text editors – and now you mention office suites. You explicitly wrote you don't want formatting, image integration etc… I had no idea Gobby was like that. In this case, you might also wish to take a look at Collabora.

Comment: @Izzy my question is indeed about a plain text editor, Ms Word and Office 365 don't quite match it, though Ms Word can easily save as plain text (no formatting, images e.t.c.) ! So Ms Word can operate like a text editor it terms of functionality, so in a sense it can be a bit like a bulky text editor "effectively".  I did say though,  "not in a web browser".

Comment: Ah, OK. Wasn't clear whether that argument got dropped along :D

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can see so far is using an office suits with collaborative editing, but simply not using the extra formatting.

This videos hows Next Cloud is a collaborative word processor that has the collaborative features of google docs, but  can operate outside of a web browser, and edit files directly from your computer.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxX_Z6BKySw

I wouldn't necessarily trust Word 2013 for if a network connection goes down and you are editing a file on a network drive, Ms Word 2019 may be better with that. But Ms Word is capable of functioning rather like a text editor. I tested this in Ms Word 2013.  If you open a text file and try to put something in there that isn't text, then it warns you before saving, and if you go ahead then it saves it without the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [*Code with Me* plugin for Intellij IDEA](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2020/10/23/code-with-me-jetbrains-ides-v2020-3/) would be an option, which can be also used with the community edition of IDEA.